# Why can't I add to ee lists with List.add?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I was trying to create a list with the following code to then classify:

```
  var randomStratClassifierIterator = function(times){

  var loops = 0;
  var classified = ee.List([]);
  
  while(loops < times){
  
    //Classify image and add to a list
    classified.add(ee.Image(0))); 
    
    loops += 1;
  }
  
  return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(classified).reduce(ee.Reducer.median(2)); 
  
};
```

But it won't add to the list. I then tested this outside of the function and I can't use List.add() to append anything at all. I switched to using a non-EE list and using .push(), which works fine but I'm wondering if I'm using .add() wrong? It seems like it should be straightforward and the docs show it should support ee objects, strings, etc (none of which worked for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Earth Engine functions (except those in `ee.data` and a few other special cases which actually make API calls or manipulate UI elements) *return new values;* they do not modify the object they're called on. `classified.add(ee.Image(0));` constructs a list one element bigger, and then immediately throws it away since you didn't assign it to anything. Instead,

```
classified = classified.add(ee.Image(0));
```

will do what you intended. Full loop snippet:

```
  var loops = 0;
  var classified = ee.List([]);
  while (loops < times) {
    classified = classified.add(ee.Image(0)); 
    loops += 1;
  }
```

---

However, when you are constructing a list *with a client-side loop* (`while`) like you are right now, it's actually better overall to do it using a JavaScript array ("non-EE list") — the resulting representation is slightly more compact and will take slightly less time for the Earth Engine servers to handle.

```
  var loops = 0;
  var classified = [];
  while (loops < times) {
    classified.push(ee.Image(0)); 
    loops += 1;
  }
```

Also, it is more concise and idiomatic JavaScript to use a `for` loop instead of `while`, which puts the initialization and increment together with the condition:

```
  var classified = [];
  for (var loops = 0; loops < times; loops += 1) {
    classified.push(ee.Image(0)); 
  }
```

---

In the specific case of making a list of identical values, you can use the even simpler option `ee.List.repeat(ee.Image(0), times)`, but I assume that in your actual code you want to run a classifier differently for each time rather than producing a collection of all identical images.

If the loop doesn't actually require other client-side computation, then you can use `ee.List.sequence` and `map` to construct a list from individually computed items (which will execute the `map` operation on the server, so it is better when you have lots of items):

```
var classified =
  ee.List.sequence(1, times)
    .map(function (n) {
       return ee.Image(...);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply! I knew it would be something simple that I was just missing. Good to know about for/while as well.

Comment: Also, you're right that `ee.image(0)` is a filler. In my actual code I'm classifying the same image x times using different random training points each time, then adding each classified image to the list and finally reducing to get the median classified value. Are you saying it would be more efficient to create a list of x images and then use `map` on the list?

Comment: @golrock Since the thing that differs is the training point collections, not the images, you should construct a list of *those*, probably using the `ee.List.sequence(1, times).map(...)` method, convert the list to a feature collection, and map over it to produce the collection of classified images.